# Accessing Children in Custom FXML Component Init

Tags: java, javafx

If I have a custom JavaFX component like this (for e.g.):

```
public class MenuWidget extends VBox implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    StackPane menus;

    public MenuWidget() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/MenuWidget.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(menus.getChildren().size());
    }
}
```

With this FXML:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <StackPane fx:id="menus">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="5" left="5" bottom="5" right="5"></Insets>
        </padding>
    </StackPane>    
</fx:root>
```

And I use the custom component like this in another FXML file:

```
<MenuWidget>
    <menus>
        <fx:include source="FirstMenu.fxml" />
        <fx:include source="SecondMenu.fxml" />
    </menus>            
</MenuWidget>
```

Why does the Initialize() method in MenuWidget print 0? Essentially I need to access the children of the stackpane when the MenuWidget is constructed so that I can setup other menu controls of the top level menu (which I've removed from this example). Shouldn't the FXMLLoader populate the controller (the MenuWidget) with all its properties before the init method is called?

EDIT: Figured out the init is called before constructor finishes, so tried moving init code into the constructor (after the fmxmlLoader.load() call) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: A better solution might be to move the constructor code into `initialize`, and after that's done, do your println again and see what happens

Comment: Good idea! Tried that, and now another issue is uncovered. First I got a coercion error (it wanted to coerse one of the sub menus to a StackPane). Then I added <children> tags to <menus> and I get "Parent element does not support property elements".

Comment: Your `MenuWidget` class does not define any list property named `menus`, so the `<menus>` element in the FXML file should be causing errors.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wanted to add the sub-menus as children of the StackPane (there is a StackPane property in the MenuWidget class). Since <children> is the "default" property in FXML, I thought adding them inside <menus> would add them as children to the StackPane menus property. Does it not work that way?

Comment: As described in the answer, `MenuWidget.initialize()` is invoked during the process of loading `MenuWidget.fxml`, which happens during the `MenuWidget` constructor call (which is before items are added to the menu list). Your `initialize` method could add a listener to `menus.getChildren()` and update whatever it is you need to update as items are added (note, though, that you can't modify the same `menus.getChildren()` list in such a listener). This just might not be the right solution at all; it's difficult to know without more details of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MenuWidget` class and its associated FXML file are entirely self-contained. You aren't including anything there and you are not adding any children to the `StackPane`. In other words, this:

```java
public class MenuWidget extends VBox implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    StackPane menus;

    public MenuWidget() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/MenuWidget.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(menus.getChildren().size());
    }
}
```

Loads this:

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <StackPane fx:id="menus">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="5" left="5" bottom="5" right="5"></Insets>
        </padding>
    </StackPane>    
</fx:root>
```

And once it's finished with that, the `initialize` method is invoked. Nothing there added anything to `menus` so the result of calling `menus.getChildren().size()` is of course `0`.

Somewhere else you are loading this:

```xml
<MenuWidget>
    <menus>
        <fx:include source="FirstMenu.fxml" />
        <fx:include source="SecondMenu.fxml" />
    </menus>            
</MenuWidget>
```

Which causes a `MenuWidget` to be instantiated, which involves calling the `MenuWidget#initialize` method, **and then** attempts to add children to `menus`. To put it another way, if this was valid and working FXML, then the children would be added **after** the `MenuWidget` instance was created and initialized.

However, the `<menus>` element should be causing your application to throw an exception. The `MenuWidget` class does not define a [read-only list property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements) named `menus`. If you want to uses `<menus>`, and you want elements of that list to be added to the children of the `menus` stack pane, then modify your `MenuWidget` class to be:

```java
public class MenuWidget extends VBox implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    StackPane menus;

    public MenuWidget() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/MenuWidget.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(menus.getChildren().size());
    }

    // add read-only list property (the "property" is read-only, not 
    // the list itself) named "menus"
    public final ObservableList<Node> getMenus() {
        return menus.getChildren();
    }
}
```

But that seems conceptually wrong (at least to me). I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but maybe you should be `fx:include`-ing the other FXML files directly into the `MenuWidget` FXML file, rather than what you're currently doing. That way you could inject the controllers and/or views (see [nested controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)) into the `MenuWidget` class. I'm also not sure if the use of `fx:root` is entirely warranted in this case, based on what you've shown us. Inheriting from `VBox` does not seem to be adding any benefit to your code (i.e. you're not adding any functionality)—especially since you're only adding a single child to it (then adding children to that child). Perhaps a standard FXML file + controller would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply. I removed a lot of surrounding code for simplicity. MenuWidget is a custom component used for displaying a set of sub-menus. The MenuWidget component has other controls for navigating through the menus. The idea is that MenuWidgets can be used in multiple places/projects, with custom menus added to it elsewhere. The only logic inside MenuWidget is the logic for changing between menus. I had assumed that MenuWidget#Initialise() was called *after* the FXML graph was fully loaded (i.e. after all children had been added to it) (which as you've explained is wrong).

Comment: If I'm being pedantic, the `initialize` method _is_ loaded after the entire FXML graph has been fully loaded. It's just you have _two_ loads occurring due to the nature of `fx:root`.